# How to fill a bezier path with control points with gradient color

Tags: ios, uibezierpath, cagradientlayer

I need to fill my bezier path with a gradient color. But the effect is not what I expected, I know this is caused by the drawing direction.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVYmK.png]

How can I achieve the effect of the second picture?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIIx5.png]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

my bezierpath code

```
        CGFloat deltaX = lineChartPoint.x - previousLineChartPoint.x;
        CGFloat controlPointX = previousLineChartPoint.x + (deltaX / 2);

        CGPoint controlPoint1 = CGPointMake(controlPointX, previousLineChartPoint.y);
        CGPoint controlPoint2 = CGPointMake(controlPointX, lineChartPoint.y);

        [bezierPath addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(lineChartPoint.x, lineChartPoint.y) controlPoint1:controlPoint1 controlPoint2:controlPoint2];
```

my gradientLayer code

```
self.gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    self.gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(kVPadding, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) - 2 * kVPadding, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
    self.gradientLayer.colors = @[(__bridge id)[UIColor colorWithHex:0x8362FC alpha:0.9].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor colorWithHex:0x517DF7 alpha:0.1].CGColor];
    self.gradientLayer.locations=@[@0.0,@1.0];
    self.gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);
    self.gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,1);
    [self.layer addSublayer:self.gradientLayer];

    self.gradientShapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    self.gradientLayer.mask = self.gradientShapeLayer;
    self.gradientShapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
```

@Dragonthoughts